# Link to a specific tab of an external page

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, tabs

I need to put a link on my website which go to another website (so far nothing complicated :D)
The problem is that the page where the link goes has a content organized with tabs like that :

```
<div id="tabcontent1" style="display: block;">...</div>
<div id="tabcontent2" style="display: none;">...</div>
<div id="tabcontent3" style="display: none;">...</div>
<div id="tabcontent4" style="display: none;">...</div>
```

And the content is hidden/shown through javascript call :

```
<a href="#" onclick="selectTab(4); return false;"></a>
```

What I want to do is making my link to point to this page with the last tab shown. Since I do not control the page itself (not on my website), I don't know how I can do this.

Do you guys have any idea how I can do it ?

Comment: You can't do this unless the other website has a way of enabling/disabling those tabs from the URL somehow.

Comment: Unless that page allows the tab to be shown based on its `id`/hash-fragment, you can't.

Answer (score 0):

Take an example of StackOverflow site

Now I will provide a link on my site, which will land on last tab of Stackoverflow

> **URL:** https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered

Here we have a facility through the url which can land on any tab.

But in your case, you need to see the targeted site has the same privilege to do so.

Comment: That's what I thought. Looks like the only way for me to achieve this is to use an iframe...

Comment: In fact, even with iframe, I am not able to inject javascript in it (at least on Chrome). Looks like there is no solution...

Comment: @user1534422: Are you sure, tab links are same as the actual site link?